# Domainname for Facebook login

Tags: facebook, authentication, domain-name

For my website I want to add a facebook login. Now, when I want to create a new app on the Facebook Developers website they ask a domainname for my app. I don't have a domain. I'm still working on my site and I'm just working local on my localhost. What do I have to give in at that place? localhost, 127.0.0.1 and my IP Adress will not work.

http://d.pr/i/hUo9

Comment: You can test login on localhost, just put a localhost address into the “Website with Facebook login” field.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I think having a domain name is required, because they can't check your website when it's on a local machine.
If everyone would just use localhost/127.0.0.1 there is no way for them to check that you use their data for legitimate reasons.

Comment: localhost, 127.0.0.1 or even my IP adress (read it somewhere as a possible solution) will not work

Answer (score 0):

Go through the Facebook app options and create a site on Heroku. It's free until your site is actually getting used (10,000+ db records and continuous traffic).  You'll get a default domain name like "blissful-swan-3847.herokuapp.com", and you can edit the sub-domain to your liking or just paste the default into facebook. They even have a default facebook app ready to go in the language of your choice: Ruby-on-Rails, PHP, NodeJS, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. This kinda website includes a lot of facebook, also a login with fb? Because you have a lot of information shown on it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question. Are you asking if the Heroku sample app includes fb login code? It does. It has a login, the open-graph syntax, a grid showing photos of your friends, and a list of your app's users.